# Language-agnostic syntax for referencing a variable outside of code

Tags: syntax, coding-style

So, I often find myself wanting to reference a generic variable in documentation, docstrings, notes-to-self, etc. I usually end up doing something like `<variable_name>` or `%variable_name` to indicate that a given word is also a variable, but this seems a bit hackneyed or at the very least arbitrary.

Is anyone aware of a generally-accepted method for referencing variables outside of code itself, or able to argue the merits of one or another suggested method?

I am aware that this question may sit atop the very summit of Mt. Esoterica, but I'd be fascinated to hear if others have come across/solved this issue.

Comment: "able to argue the merits of" - and _that's_ the point at which this question becomes subjective :-) FWIW, I see nothing wrong with `<varName>` or something similar provided you explain somewhere in the doc that it's not literal.

Comment: @paxdiablo guilty as charged - I am certainly not expecting stone tablet levels of divine truth here. :)

Comment: @paxdiablo Were you suggesting quotes too?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people use foo and bar in generic sentences like this one. See how i didn't style them or tell you they were variable names and you still understood me?

Comment: Although I like the efficiency, it strikes me as a bit limited for general applications, specifically if you want to use variable names that communicate something about the information contained within them.

Comment: Foo and bar are good for programmers but mean very little to users.